# Unexpected token (,) when mapping an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to map an array in React (using this code):

```
const { loading, error, posts } = this.props;
    return(
    {posts.map(onePost => ({
        <p key={onePost.id}>{onePost.title}</p>

    }))}
    );
```

I get an error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/client/app/mainGrid.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/[redacted]/react/src/client/app/mainGrid.jsx: Unexpected token, expected , (15:8)

  13 |          return(
  14 |
> 15 |          {posts.map(onePost => ({
     |                ^
  16 |                  <p key={onePost.id}>{onePost.title}</p>
  17 |
  18 |          }))}

 @ ./src/client/app/index.jsx 27:16-41
```

I have no idea why is this happening, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: I'd say the inner-most `{}` are causing the problem - either wrap the JSX element in just parens, i.e. `( <p...> )` not `({ <p...> })` or return an ordinary object

Comment: You're returning an *object*, it's assuming `posts` is shorthand for `posts: posts` and expecting a comma before the next key.

Answer (score 9):

I cleaned up your snippet, you have too many parenthesis that are not needed. To get into details, wrapping your return statement in `{}` is telling js you are returning an object, but you are trying to return an expression (which in turn returns an array). In order to let js evaluate that expression you wrap it into `()`, which is then normally returned.

You do that twice as you add additional `{}` even in your arrow function inside the `.map`, same explanations as before.

```
const { loading, error, posts } = this.props;

return (
  posts.map(onePost => (
    <p key={onePost.id}>{onePost.title}</p>
  )
);
```

In this case you can go one step further and remove the parenthesis in your return statement as well:

```
const { loading, error, posts } = this.props;

return posts.map(onePost => <p key={onePost.id}>{onePost.title}</p>);
```